# Difficulty putting a javascript code in a refresh of an html page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add this random code in an HTML refresh.
Once the refresh is triggered, it generates a random sequence and adds to the testing123 link.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function generateRandomString(n) {
        let randomString = '';
        let characters =
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          randomString += characters.charAt(
            Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
          );
        }
        return randomString;
      }
    </script>

    <meta
      http-equiv="refresh"
      content="1; URL='https://testing1234.serveirc.com/view.php?id="
    />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      generateRandomString(25);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<meta` belongs in `<head>` and having to need both `'` and `"` inside an attribute is problematic - made easier if you don't try to put a script tag in a URL of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to generate the random part of the URL client-side with JavaScript, it would make more sense to perform the redirect with JavaScript than to construct a `<meta>` tag for it.

```
<script>
function generateRandomString(n) {
    let randomString     = '';
    let characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      randomString += characters[Math.floor(Math.random()*characters.length)];
   }
   return randomString;
}
setTimeout(() => {
  window.location.href = `https://testing1234.serveirc.com/view.php?id=${generateRandomString(25)}`;
}, 1000); // Redirect after 1 second
</script>
```

Using a meta tag makes more sense if you can construct the random part from server-side code that constructs the HTML (such as with PHP or Handlebars or some scripting template engine).